# Return from call from C++ into DLL skips at least one call stack frame

Tags: c++, dll, callstack

I have the weird problem that when I call a function in a DLL (a DLL made by someone else), when the function return it doesn't return to where one would expect it to, namely to the statement immediately following the statement that called the function, but to somewhere higher up in the call stack. I first thought it could be a problem related to the calling convention so I tried out about all non-deprecated calling conventions, but the problem didn't disappear. Here's the code:

```
typedef LPXLOPER12 (WINAPI *LPFNDLLFUNC1)();

std::wstring LoadDllAndCallOneFunction()
{
    HINSTANCE hDLL;  // Handle to DLL
    LPFNDLLFUNC1 lpfnDllFunc1;  // Function pointer
    std::wstring retval(L"Error");

    hDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:/Program Files (x86)/SRLib/EcmUtils.xll"));
    if (hDLL != NULL)
    {
        lpfnDllFunc1 = (LPFNDLLFUNC1)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "_ExcelFunctionSlot_0_0_5@0");
        if (!lpfnDllFunc1)
        {
            FreeLibrary(hDLL);
        }
        else
        {
            LPXLOPER12 uReturnVal = lpfnDllFunc1();  // <--- The return from this call goes somewhere high up in the call stack, it even leaves the WndProc message handler that calls this function
            retval = uReturnVal->val.str;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD ec;
        ec = GetLastError();
    }

    return retval;
}
```

It doesn't break at the break-point that I set right after the function call, neither does it return the retval value.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you sure you're using the exact calling convention for that function?  Are there any other "initialisation" calls that need to be made into the DLL for global state or whatever?  This type of thing can happen when an exception is not caught in the DLL, and crosses the boundary back to the caller.  Or if your calling convention is wrong and messes up the stack.

Comment: Another possibility is maybe the definition of `LPXLOPER12` does not match.  Potentially it has different padding or data sizes than the one used in the DLL.  Although this wouldn't explain why you never hit the next line (unless you're debugging a Release build)

Comment: WINAPI is __stdcall, which is a callee-clean convention, so getting the arguments wrong *will* mess up the stack. So check that.